# Formataçao PYTHON

Tags: python

podem me dar uma dica de como imprimir o seguinte problema da maneira correta?

```
while True:
    m = int(input())
    mlen = m
    sm = 1
    aux = 1
    matriz = []

    if m == 0:
        print()
        break

    for i in range(m):
        linha = []
        for j in range(m):
            linha.append(sm)
        matriz.append(linha)

    while m - 2 > 0:
        for i in range(aux, m - 1):
            for j in range(aux, m - 1):
                matriz[i][j] = sm + 1
        sm += 1
        aux += 1
        m -= 1
    for i in matriz:
        for j in i:
            print('{:4}'.format(j), end='')
        print('')
```

Preciso que a matriz impressa tenha 2 espaços do lado esquerdo, 3 espaços entre os valores e nenhum espaço no final de cada linha. É um exercício do URI Online Judge - 1435.

```
    Accepted Output             Your Output
1   ··1···1···1···1         1   ···1···1···1···1
2   ··1···2···2···1         2   ···1···2···2···1
3   ··1···2···2···1         3   ···1···2···2···1
4   ··1···1···1···1         4   ···1···1···1···1
6   ··1···1···1···1···1     6   ···1···1···1···1···1
7   ··1···2···2···2···1     7   ···1···2···2···2···1
8   ··1···2···3···2···1     8   ···1···2···3···2···1
9   ··1···2···2···2···1     9   ···1···2···2···2···1
10  ··1···1···1···1···1     10  ···1···1···1···1···1
```

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o enunciado completo do exercício, também, pois facilitará no entendimento da questão.

Comment: Atenção que a forma como disse o que precisa não está certa. Os valores são justificados à direita em tamanho `3` e separados por espaço. Logo se tiver o numero `11`, vai ter 1 espaço antes devido à justificação e outro para separar dos restantes elementos.

Answer (score 1):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **"1435"**, cujo título é **"Matriz Quadrada I"**, disponibilizado por **"Uri Online Judge"** (Maratona Online de Programação).

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1435) a íntegra do enunciado.

Para resolver esta questão você tem que saber como montar uma matriz quadrada. Além disso, deve levar em consideração as restrições que o problema nos faz.

Para resolver esta questão, podes utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
# Problema: 1435
# Título: Matriz Quadrada I
# Categoria: Iniciante
# Disponibilizado por: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1435

while True:
    N = int(input())

    if N == 0:
        break

    resultado = []

    for i in range(N):
        tmp = []
        for j in range(N):
            tmp.append(1)
        resultado.append(tmp)

    valor = 1
    cima = 0
    esq = 0
    baixo = N - 1
    direita = N - 1

    if N % 2 == 0:
        meio = N / 2

    else:
        meio = (N + 1) / 2


    while valor <= meio:
        i = esq
        while i <= direita:
            resultado[cima][i] = valor
            resultado[baixo][i] = valor
            i += 1

        i = (cima + 1)
        while i < baixo:
            resultado[i][esq] = valor
            resultado[i][direita] = valor
            i += 1

        valor += 1
        cima += 1
        baixo -= 1
        esq += 1
        direita -= 1

    for i in range(N):
        tx = ''
        for j in range(N):
            tx += " %3d" % resultado[i][j]
        print(tx[1:])
    print("")
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/yevbbvrz-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.

Este algoritmo já foi `testado`, `submetido` e devidamente `aprovado` no site `Uri`, sobe linguagem de programação **Python 3**.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
m = int(input())
mlen = m
sm = 1
aux = 1
matriz = []

if m == 0:
    print()
    break

for i in range(m):
    linha = []
    for j in range(m):
        linha.append(sm)
    matriz.append(linha)

while m - 2 > 0:
    for i in range(aux, m - 1):
        for j in range(aux, m - 1):
            matriz[i][j] = sm + 1
    sm += 1
    aux += 1
    m -= 1
for i in matriz:
    for pos, j in enumerate(i): # pos vai ser o endereço do valor j
        if pos == 0: # se for a primeira coluna pos = 0
            print('{:3}'.format(j), end='')
        else:
            print('{:4}'.format(j), end='')
    print('')
```